# In SSRS How not to split same column on 2 pages

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have 20 columns on report. We have provided user to exclude columns which don't want in report. So we made hidden.

Problem is when I get report then any last column on page gets appeared some part on 1 page & some part on another page.

Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

hi i hope i understand your question correctly. you want to avoid page breake for a tablix? mark the tablix go to properies and check the PageBreak Options for me tDisabled = True works to render all informations in one page.

if it is still not working check your pagelayout in report --> report properties
also i remember there was a InteractiveHeight Option somewhere that should be set to 0.

Comment: I want page break but it should not happen the last column partly appear on first page & partly on second page. It should be on second page only.

Comment: @PravinSawant, if you want to break the page, cgo to the _tablix settings_ --> _PageBreak_--> _BreakLocation_
This should work for you.

Comment: Page break if for breaking rows data. I want mechanism to start new column on next page when there are more columns on 1 page. Currently its doing as expected only things is last column is partly appearing on 1 page & partly on 2nd page.